# Converting xls file into PDF in via cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, xls

I'm working on Visual Studio 2019 community, and I'm writing an MFC application in cpp. I want to add a functionality to the dialog box - such that when pressing a button it converts an existing `xls` file into `pdf` file. I've tried using the extension `Aspose.Cells.Cpp` and `Aspose.PDF.Cpp` with [this](https://blog.aspose.com/2021/01/19/Convert-Excel-to-PDF-using-Cpp/) code, but I get a lot of errors in the code of the DLL itself. I've also tried installing `libHARU` from [here](http://libharu.org/), but I didn't manage to make it work.

I've tried looking for another way to convert `xls` to `pdf` in MFC application in cpp, or another environment for creating desktop applications (which has some basic functionalities such as adding a pressing button in MFC, so I won't have to write everything from scratch with Win32 API), but I didn't find anything. Perhaps someone can explain to me how to perform this conversion in cpp so that I can use it when writing an MFC app, or could refer me to some useful information about another way of creating the application which supports this type of conversions?

Comment: Any program written in any programming language able to read and write files can convert from one document encoding to another document encoding. Changing the application model won't get you any closer to a solution. You seem to be grossly underestimating the effort it takes to convert from *x* to *y* (with *x* being [MS-XLS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-xls/cd03cb5f-ca02-4934-a391-bb674cb8aa06), described in a document with more than 1000 pages). The PDF documentation weighs in at slightly under 1000 pages. This is the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you very much for your comment, I guess I didn't grasp the complexity of the subject. perhaps you know if there is any existing software that I can integrate in my MFC application (even if there's need to pay for them) which will do the conversion for me?

Comment: If you can assume your user has Office installed, it would be a matter of manipulating the Office automation model. If you have to do it without Office being installed...then that is a whole other complex matter.

Comment: In my MFC app I simply let the user use a PDF Printer ...

Comment: @AndrewTruckle thank you for your comment, is there any guide that explains how to use this PDF printer from inside MFC application?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson thank you for your comment, yes I assume the user has office.

Comment: It is just a printer that the user uses themselves with the app.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle I see. I'm looking for a solution such that when a button is pressed, the xls will be converted to pdf. can it be suitable for this? sorry for the dumb question, I'm just still not 100% sure what printer exactly do you use, it's like Adobe acrobat printer? but how can I call it from within the app?

Comment: This is not free so might be an alternative solution: https://www.bullzip.com/developer.php

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Thank you for your comment, is there any piece of code in C++ that I can add into my MFC application such that when the user presses a button it automatically sends a pdf to be printer to this application?

Comment: I don’t know. Sorry. I guess that is what the api is for. Looks reasonable price.

Comment: @E.Ginzburg Did you see my answer?

Comment: @JosephWillcoxson I saw your answer and upvoted it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You said in your comments to me that you can assume the user has Excel installed on his machine. If so, then you can use Excel's automation object model to manipulate Excel. You could do stuff like `#import` the type library and stuff...maybe that would make prettier C++. My experience, however, with driving Office apps is to stick more with just raw dispatch pointers. I've had less go wrong that way. This probably needs some more error checking and stuff, but that's up to you.

... and a big caveat. This is for an interactive app...which I halfway assume since you are using the MFC topic. With a service, Microsoft does not recommend you drive their Office applications in this manner.  I tested this on  one .xlsx file and it worked. Assume it will work for .xls as well. For other formats, you might need to use different import functions.

```
void ConvertFile(LPCWSTR lpszFileIn, LPCWSTR lpszFileOut)
{
    CComDispatchDriver excel;
    if (SUCCEEDED(excel.CoCreateInstance(_T("Excel.Application"), NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER)))
    {
        _variant_t vWorkbooks;
        if (SUCCEEDED(excel.GetPropertyByName(L"Workbooks", &vWorkbooks)))
        {
            CComDispatchDriver workbooks(vWorkbooks.pdispVal);

            _variant_t vWorksheet;
            if (SUCCEEDED(workbooks.Invoke1(L"Open", &_variant_t(lpszFileIn), &vWorksheet)))
            {
                CComDispatchDriver worksheet(vWorksheet.pdispVal);

                UINT xlTypePdf = 0;
                HRESULT hr = worksheet.Invoke2(L"ExportAsFixedFOrmat", &_variant_t(xlTypePdf), &_variant_t(lpszFileOut), NULL);
                if (FAILED(hr))
                {
                    _com_error err(hr);
                    AfxMessageBox(err.ErrorMessage());
                }

            }

        }
        excel.Invoke0(L"Quit", NULL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a solution, but this one doesn't use `c++`, just command line and [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org) app:

Use command line Libre Office tool: `--convert-to`

```
--convert-to output_file_extension[:output_filter_name] [--outdir output_dir] files

Batch convert files. If --outdir is not specified, then current working directory is used as output_dir.
Eg. --convert-to pdf *.doc
--convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir /home/user *.doc
```

More details about how to use this command you'll find here: https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters

Later edit: Here is a sample of how to implement the above solution in a C++/MFC code:

```
STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
si.cb = sizeof(si);
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
sCommand.Format(_T("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe /c
C:\\LibreOffice\\program\\swriter.exe --convert-to pdf -outdir
c:\\temp\\  c:\\temp\\MyFile.doc"));
::CreateProcess(0, sCommand, 0, 0, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. I'm looking for something I can integrate into the MFC application I'm writing. I'm not sure, perhaps you know if there is any way of using the command line and LibreOffice app from my application?

Comment: I don't think you'll get solve your task then without using a PDF library, free or not.

Comment: If the requirement to have LibreOffice installed on your client's machine, as well as the results this app generates are acceptable to you, using a command-line app from your application is not a problem. You can just call the `CreateProcess()` function (pass the command-line), wait on its handle (`WaitForSingleObject()`) until it completes, and finally call `GetExitCodeProcess()` to check its return code (to see if it was successful or what went wrong). The procedure above is blocking (actually the `WaitForSingleObject()` call makes it so).

Comment: Good point Constantine. Even though LibreOffice is not installed on target machine, just lay down near by the MFC application, could be launched in a hidden command line window and do the job.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou thank you for your comment. I've been trying to implement this method, but I guess I'm still not quit familiar with those functions. is there any chance you know a guide which can explain exactly how to activate Libreoffice from within a handler of the MFC application?

Comment: @E. Ginzburg you can do whatever you want, but you need to know that you can do programmatically that command line commands to do the conversion, however, I guess using `CreateProcess` is more reliable to accomplish your task, I just want to know there is this alternative.

Comment: As I mentioned above, if the LibreOffice solution and its results are OK to you (first test them manually in a CMD window, and figure out how it will be deployed to the users' machines), all you need is call the command-line from you application. If you have trouble using the functions I listed above, better start a new thread, as it's a different topic (how to run a command-line application in general, not specific to xls-to-pdf conversion). You may get negative points though, as there are quite a few questions and examples already posted.